# How to do this swipable view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have attached an image and i wish to know how to achieve the highlighted swipable view to show images and some text.

thanks
[image: Swipable view]

Comment: I could do this and now I wish to add the whole scrollview with paging into a table cell, I am trying to put the scrollview inside the cell of a tableview but never appears I m adding the scrollview to the cell as a contentView in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, not sure whats going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use horizontal table views, as shown [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

It's a lot more scalable, will spare you all the memory management boiler-plate code, and is a lot more efficient on older version of iPhones/iPod (which have much less memory).

Edit: just to be more specific. If you know before hand that your paging doesn't need to scale up, then a standard page controller is a good solution. On the other hand, if you can't put an upper limit on the number of pages or if each page has a significant memory footprint, or requires 2d image manipulation, then horizontal table view may be a solution.

Comment: If you want do this using a table style system, I would recommend looking at `UICollectionView` which introduced in iOS 6. The author of the tutorial above wrote the tutorial before this new alternative was available. He also wrote a tutorial ons the `UICollectionView` at http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled = YES`

The dots under it are a `UIPageControl` which shows users how many pages of content there is and their position in the content.